# What headers are necessary to complete an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to access images from a Google Photos album and populate a webpage with those images. This goal has been [completed before](https://medium.com/@ValentinHervieu/how-i-used-google-photos-to-host-my-website-pictures-gallery-d49f037c8e3c), but implemented with Axios (which I'm not very familiar with). My issue is that my origin (currently a local port) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. From the tutorials and examples I've followed, including [this one from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), I thought my implementation allows the port I'm running on, but I still run into the same issue.

```
// This is not the actual album url; for privacy I have changed it
const ALBUM_URL = "https://my-google-photos-album-url";


$(document).ready(function()
{
    GetAlbum();
});

function GetAlbum()
{
    const xhr = new XHRHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", ALBUM_URL);
    // Set the origin to the port we will be using
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

**Expected Behavior:** Print a string of HTML and JS as was shown in [the linked example](https://medium.com/@ValentinHervieu/how-i-used-google-photos-to-host-my-website-pictures-gallery-d49f037c8e3c).

**Actual Behavior:** Gives an error indicating that "http://localhost:8000" is not allowed. Exact details are given below.

Error log:

> Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-google-photos-album-url due to access control checks.

> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What am I missing here? I have also tried setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*", but without any luck. Any and all help is useful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The CORS error that you get is returned by the server that you are trying to access -  the server behind the `https://my-google-photos-album-url`.

If you have access to this server, you should set there the CORS policy that will allow the client (`http://localhost:8000` in your case) to access its resources. Otherwise, I'm not sure you can access it.

Comment: Thanks! How can I set the CORS policy on the server behind the `https://my-google-photos-album-url`? Is this something that is feasible, given that it's a url to a google photos album (i.e., not a server that I control)?

Comment: I would suggest you start by looking at the Google Photos API here - https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started and then read this section https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items. I'm not super familiar with that, but it may be a good starting point.